# How to block a wrapper app around my website

Tags: android, mobile, http-headers, wrapper

Someone created a wrapper app for my website, is there a way to block or prevent browsing to my website from that app?  Like checking http headers, client or app ID..?  Is there something in the apk app to look for as unique name or id to block?  Or wrapper apps only show act as just "android" browser without unique ID?

Or how can I forward the landing page of the app to another custom page of my choice?

Comment: What is your application stack serving your site? Are the serving your whole site, or just specific assets from it?

Comment: It's serving the main page, and through the user can browse the whole site as a normal browser.

Comment: Ok - what are you using to serve your site? Nignx, Apache, ???

Comment: nginx /1. 16. 1